# sh trap SIGINT failed, but trap SIGQUIT success

Tags: linux, shell, signals

I want to trap the CtrL+c and CtrL+\, then the cmd below added into my script:

```
trap _trapException SIGINT SIGQUIT
function _trapException(){
  echo "The job is canceled!"
  exit
}
```

However, this can trap CtrL+\ but can not trap CtrL+c,
I delete the SIGQUIT, it still does not trap CtrL+c.

Otherwise, I used tee function in my script at the same time.

Comment: I removed `trap` tag as it doesn't describe the shell's `trap` but something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your handler function and trap call are fine. The function will be called when you raise either `SIGINT` or `SIGQUIT` for the first time. However, in the signal handler, you are also calling `exit`. That means it's going to kill the process.

Try removing the `exit` call from the function `_trapException`.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work after removing `exit`. Can you post a short code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: sorry, the input box is too small, then I add the description below. thx

Comment: How did you manage to send signal to your program as it would in a fraction of a second? You call `exit` from `test.sh` and it's going to kill. Any signal you send from commandline is going to be received by `test.sh`. I can't reproduce your problem. What's your `sh`?

Comment: GNU bash(bdsh), version 3.00.22(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: I update the trap_test.sh(the whole contents) and test.sh, then you can rerun them once again, 
the demo just to show the problem, and my real script may has something wrong like this

Answer (score 0):

@Blue Moon I found what causes the problem when I rewrite a demo code to reproduce it. The demo as below: 
test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
#encoding:UTF-8

trap _trapException SIGINT SIGQUIT
function _trapException(){
    echo "INFO: The job is canceled!"
    exit 1
}

sh trap_test.sh | tee -a test.log
```

while the trap_test.sh also has a trap function, the function like below:

```
#!/bin/shell
trap test SIGINT SIGQUIT
function test(){
    echo "trap test!"
    exit 1
 }

 while true
 do
    echo "test"
    sleep 10
 done
```

when I run sh test.sh, then trap the CtrL+c failed, however trap Ctrl+\ success;
when I delete the trap code in trap_test.sh , it can trap both signal when run sh test.sh.

The deep reason still unknown?